# VBA Userform Listbox into SQL temp table

Tags: sql, vba

I have userform in Excel VBA that contains two multiselect listboxes. Essentially its the add/remove concept where the box on the left gives me a lits of analysis names from SQL and you select the ones you want into the box on the right.

What I'm now trying to do is take the information in the list box that the user wants to use and put that into a temp table in SQL so that I can run a query that loops through the values in the temp table.

I was going to create a .csv file save if and then inser the temp table into SQL. However that seemed long winded and made me think there must be a more direct way, however this is beyhond my SQL/VBA skills.

Many Thanks

Comment: Don't really see what you are asking for there? Do you need help with setting up the VBA code to the SQL server? What have you got so far?

Comment: Its more the code to save data from a listbox into a temp table. Access to the server is fine and normally I can pass data from SQL into VBA its just going the other way I have no experience with and not even sure if it is possible without the csv method? Thanks

Comment: You could simply create a query inside VBA which would add the data to the temp table. So it would be, in pseudo code, "INSERT INTO #temptable VALUES(" & listbox column 1.value & "," listbox column 2.value & ")" You just need to put that into vba code and then send the insert query to the sql server from vba